# C# Nested for loops creating unexpected results depending on braces

Tags: c#, for-loop, nested

I seem to be having a problem when creating nested for loops with C#. When the nested Loop has braces, the result isn't as expected, whereas with braces the result is as expected.

The code:

```
int i, j, k;

for(i=1; i<=5;i++) // this loops 5 times. 
{
   for (j = 5; j > i; j--)
   {
      Console.Write(" ");
      Console.WriteLine("0");
   }
}
```

Expected:

```
    0
   0
  0
 0
0
```

Result:

```
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
```

I don't understand why, if I negate the nested braces, I will get the expected answer, but I am unsure why with them it doesn't work.

Comment: This is what debuggers are for.

Comment: You should single step the program in the debugger and watch the output. Doing so will let you see immediately why the output is not what you expected.

Comment: One question - what do you think curly braces do in C#? Also think about whether indentation matters or not

Comment: My primary use for Brackets is because I believe it helps with readability of code. However, I understand they have something to do with initialisation of an object, but I don't fully understand. The last language I used was very strict with them, so I use them still (JS in unity3d). 

I will use the debugger, once I'm aware of it.

Comment: I'm aware of it. (Debugger, that is).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the braces in the wrong place, try this:

```
 int i, j, k;

 for(i=1; i<=5;i++) // this loops 5 times. 
 {
    for (j = 5; j > i; j--)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("0");
 }
```

If you don't put braces, it works because only the sentence below the `for` statement is in the loop

```
 for(i=1; i<=5;i++) // loop A
 {
    for (j = 5; j > i; j--)  // loop B
        Console.Write(" ");  // in scope of loop B
    Console.WriteLine("0");  // in scope of loop A
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

take this `Console.WriteLine("0");`out of the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Because Console.WriteLine("0"); will give a return.

Try this

```
   for(i=1; i<=5;i++) // this loops 5 times. 
    {
        for (j = 5; j > i; j--)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("0");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be done in a shorter way:

```
for(int i = 5; i > 0; --i)
    Console.WriteLine(new String(' ', i) + 0);
```